# How to pass a string from PHP into an html tag?

Tags: php, html

I have a string, an img url, in a php block called $str. And I want to set that string as the img src in an img src but its not working.

```
<img src="<?php $str ?>" height="50px" width="50px">
```

how else can i set the src to the $str string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo $str;?>" height="50px" width="50px">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo '<img src="'.$str.'" height="50px" width="50px">' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other ways, although is not recommended. You may try :

```
<img src="<?=$str?>" height="50px" width="50px">
```

this will work, only if (in php.ini)

> short_open_tag = On

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found correct answer for this problem. Nothing works well from above answers, that codes only print out source string to html page on site.

This works for me (I have my function that return source string of picture):

`require_once("../../my_coded_php_functions.php");`

**`<?php echo '<img src="' . getSourcePathOfImage() . '" />' ?>`**

This site(article) helped me to find and understand solution:

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php